# Android Studio | Error "resource not found" for no longer called resource

Tags: java, android

fist off all the code:
Following lines are in my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    View view = findViewById(R.id.action_item_two);

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_item_one) {
        // Do thing one
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_item_two) {
        // Do thing two
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My menu has the file res/menu/main.xml and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Hilfe">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forward_30_48px"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Sekunden">
    </item>

</menu>
```

In an old version of the main menu I used drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24 as icon-source to test the menu and it worked.

After this I changed the icon-sources to the final ones, but the icons where still the old one.

I deleted the old icon source (drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24 and from now on I have the following error when trying to start the app:
[datafile to the app]\app\src\main\res\menu\main.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24 (aka [...]:drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24) not found.

In line 4 of old menu version stood the old icon-source but now it stands nowhere and I have no idea how to solve this error.

I tried to restart everything including (invalidate Caches and restarting Android Studio)

I hope somebody can help!
Thanks

Comment: Hi R D, can you check at the `drawable` folders. if there is any `ic_baseline_pause_24` available

Comment: Hey Ticherhaz, 
there is no longer the icon calles "ic_baseline_pause_24" in the drawable folder I deleted it, because I do not longer use it.
If I add it back in the folder, it will be used and the old version, in which I used that icon as test, will be seen in the app.

For me it looks like changes in the main.xml are no longer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution to my problem...

It was i syntax-error in main.xml

It has to be:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_item_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Hilfe"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_item_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_forward_30_48px"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Sekunden">
</item>
```

Cause this error the menu did not update